# Python performance issue when inserting into remote database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, performance, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to run a local python script on my computer that inserts records on a remote database upon events like clicks, window change, ect. I am using `sqlalchemy` to connect to a `postgres` database.

The problem is that my computer slows down significantly (I won't use it like that). I was using a local `sqlite` database for testing and it worked fine, then switch to the remote `postgres` and this performance issue appeared.

I know python is synchronous and http requests are slow but I have 4 cores so technically other processes shouldn't slow down this much. How can I avoid this? I am running on windows.

**Update:**
The frequency of events is very high since every click, window change, and some keystrokes trigger an insert.

Comment: You should probably elaborate on how many / how frequently you're making inserts into the database and maybe check how much time a single insert takes.

Comment: Access database is IO bound, so number of core is not effect, maybe it's because your network latency so slow, if you have problems with io bound you can use gevent, or thread

Answer (score -1):

The slowdown you are seeing is the latency of your network connection to the server.

If you are inserting rows in a for loop, each row will be create and execute one query to the database. In the process, sqlalchemy has to wait for the result of each query to be sent back through the network. Even in very low latency networks it can add up to significant times.

For example:

```
Adding 10,000 rows in a loop
Time to insert a row: 1us
Latency to the server: 1ms
Total time: 10,000 * 1ms + 10,000 * 1us = 10,01 s
```

You can solve this by adding several rows at once. This way, you will create only one query:

For example:

```
Adding 10,000 rows at once
Time to insert a row: 1us
Latency to the server: 1ms
Total time: 1 * 1ms + 10,000 * 1us = 0,011 s
```

Comment: As stated, I don't insert in a loop, its a continuos process.

Comment: There is no difference in this case... A loop IS a high frequency insertion sequence

Comment: Depending on the situation I may not be able to batch results. Even so, I think a mere click is slowing down the process. It makes me think that the problem has more to do with `blocking IO` in general.

Comment: Well, you should profile your code and see where it is spending most of its time.